# Running a new thread with a runtime restriction android

Tags: android, multithreading

I would like to activate a new thread with a runtime limited

How do I activate a new thread

But I do not that he stuck  my app

So if it lasts longer than 5 seconds I want to kill it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop a service after sometime, you could add below codes in your `onCreate()` method of your `service` class.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        stopSelf(); 
    }
}, 5000);
```

But I suggest you use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService), which will be stopped when there is no work for it.

**Edit**:
  If you want to kill the service by click a button, you could get current time and compare an initial time, when it exceeds 5 seconds, call [stopService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent).)

Comment: But this is not an action done on the ON CREATE
It is executed in ON CLICK

Comment: The action I want to perform is not SERVICE

Comment: In your question, you said " I would like to activate a new thread with a runtime limited ".

Comment: In your OnClick() method,you start the service, and in service, after 5 seconds, terminate itself using my answer.

Comment: @yoelisrarel may be you want to kill the server by click, please see my edited answer.

Comment: cannot reslove mentod stopself();

Comment: But it is not a service
Just a method